# Eclipse - An Error Has Occured

Tags: java, eclipse

For some reason I'm no longer able to fire up eclipse as every time I open it, i get an error that states : An error has occures, see log file x.log

- I looked around online for this issue and one of the things that seamed to have solved it is by deleting all .snap files from .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources folder but I couldn't find any .snap files (PS: this is now a clean install of eclipse)
- I also tried re-installating JDK and JRE

java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)

- I also tried running eclipse with cmd with eclipse - clean command but same error pops up.

I'm very new at this..can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong :)

Here's the log file:

```
    !SESSION 2014-09-04 23:03:28.569 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20060921-0945
java.version=1.7.0_60
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=fr_CA
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY system.bundle 4 0 2014-09-04 23:03:28.777
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent.ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle system.bundle.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:1010)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:966)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.launch(StartLevelManager.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundle.resume(SystemBundle.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.OSGi.launch(OSGi.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:173)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:952)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.checkSystemState(BaseStorage.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.getStateManager(BaseStorage.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.getPlatformAdmin(BaseAdaptor.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAdaptorHook.frameworkStart(EclipseAdaptorHook.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.frameworkStart(BaseAdaptor.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:991)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
    ... 18 more
Root exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.checkSystemState(BaseStorage.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.getStateManager(BaseStorage.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.getPlatformAdmin(BaseAdaptor.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAdaptorHook.frameworkStart(EclipseAdaptorHook.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.frameworkStart(BaseAdaptor.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:991)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:966)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.launch(StartLevelManager.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundle.resume(SystemBundle.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.OSGi.launch(OSGi.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:173)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:952)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-09-04 23:03:28.783
!MESSAGE Startup error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle system.bundle.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.launch(StartLevelManager.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundle.resume(SystemBundle.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.OSGi.launch(OSGi.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:173)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:952)
!SESSION Thu Sep 04 23:03:28 EDT 2014 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.launcher 4 0 2014-09-04 23:03:28.791
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:952)
```

Comment: Retry it with the current version. The date stamp on that build is almost 8 years old. You are also trying to run a 32-bit Eclipse with a 64-bit Java. They have always had to match.

Comment: Are you refering to the current version of Eclypse ? If so, the reason why I'm using this version is because I'm following an online course from stanford who provides this version with addons that go with the course..any idea on how I can get it to run though..it was running fine until I installed Netbeans actually now that I think about it..and Netbeans isn't even in my system anymore

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the .metadata file and again restart the eclips with the workspace. Due to some changes the metadata may be holding the older information related to eclipse and workspace.

Answer (score 0):

After I installed JDK 1.9, I got this error and changed it to 1.8.

Answer (score -1):

you should change jdk for 1.8,it will be ok.

Comment: Please specify why the OP should change its jdk to 1.8 .